# Active Directory + CNAME

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns, dns-hosting

I have active directory set up for foo.example.com 
I have an apache server behind an AWS ELB at awselb.amazon.example.com

I want my internal users to have access to all active directory resources at foo.example.com but I also want them to access the apache web server at foo.example.com

This is causing several problems.

Active Directory automatically registers A records at foo.example.com for the Domain Controllers.][2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759550(v=ws.10).aspx)

[image: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759550(v=ws.10).aspx]

This means I can't register a CNAME at the same address on the Active Directory DNS server.

I could likely fix that by putting the apache web server at a static IP address and using an A record, but then there are two A records that I do not want to resolve for my domain.

I'm wondering if I can disable this root level DNS entry. I'm also wondering what services will break if I do that.

Comment: I don't see any solution for your situation. They have same name - how is it possible for any DNS server to treat queries differently for same name? Member machines of AD must use a DNS that resolve "AD domain" names. For non-AD machines, you can just use external DNS. Anyway, alias has no use, neither does another A record.

Comment: MS specifies that this A record is for non-SRV-Aware clients. There aren't really examples of non srv aware clients. This TechTarget article also suggests that you can turn off individual automatic DNS settings: http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Preventing-DNS-registration-of-certain-SRV-records

I think it might be possible.

Comment: If you are talking about create a cname or disable dynamic update on DNS that serves AD (usually runs on DC itself), don't do it. It will affect everything AD. A records for DCs and SRV records are fundamental things for AD to work. And It won't work - how do you expect DNS to know which IP to return when there are multiple IPs for one name (default is round robin for A records).

Comment: Cant you get your internal users to use www.foo.example.com to access the website? that way you only need to add the correct A record to DNS

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should have an internal domain (local.example.com or whatever else) and Split DNS.

I don't recommend you have it set up the way I describe below, but it is the only solution to give the end users the experience they want.

Externally:
Assign www.foo.example.com and foo.example.com to the public IP of your AWS instance.

Internally:
Install a web service on your domain controllers and have your DC's website redirect your users from foo.example.com to www.foo.example.com,  you can do this with Javascript.